# EF 5 ENUM with Navigation

Tags: enums, entity-framework-5, entity-relationship

I'm trying to use Enum support with EF 5 and dot.NET 4.5.

The situation I have is the following.

POCO:

```
public partial class tbl_pp_Message

    {
        public tbl_pp_Message()
        {
            this.tbl_pp_MessageDistribution = new List<tbl_pp_MessageDistribution>();
        }

        public int MessageId { get; set; }
        public string Subject { get; set; }
        public string From { get; set; }
        public string Body { get; set; }
        public int PriorityId { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }
        public int CreateById { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("PriorityId")]
        public virtual tbl_pp_MessagePriority tbl_pp_MessagePriority { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<tbl_pp_MessageDistribution> tbl_pp_MessageDistribution { get; set; }
    }





public partial class tbl_pp_MessagePriority

    {
        public tbl_pp_MessagePriority()
        {
            this.tbl_pp_Message = new List<tbl_pp_Message>();
        }

        public int MessagePriorityId { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> DisplayOrder { get; set; }
        public bool ShowAlert { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<tbl_pp_Message> tbl_pp_Message { get; set; }
    }
```

With the code listed above NOT using an ENUM the world is happy.

When I try to add an Enum the POCO will look like this.

```
 [Flags]
    public enum MessagePriorityEnum : int

    {
        NONE = 0,
        Urgent = 1,
        Normal = 2,
        Low = 3
    }

 public partial class tbl_pp_Message

    {
        public tbl_pp_Message()
        {
            this.tbl_pp_MessageDistribution = new List<tbl_pp_MessageDistribution>();
        }

        public int MessageId { get; set; }
        public string Subject { get; set; }
        public string From { get; set; }
        public string Body { get; set; }
        public MessagePriorityEnum PriorityId { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }
        public int CreateById { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("PriorityId")]
        public virtual tbl_pp_MessagePriority tbl_pp_MessagePriority { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<tbl_pp_MessageDistribution> tbl_pp_MessageDistribution { get; set; }
    }
```

This will not work during a save because it doesn't like the ForeignKey attribute. This error will be thrown during a save.

Schema specified is not valid. Errors:

(129,6) : error 0112: The types of all properties in the Dependent Role of a referential constraint must be the same as the corresponding property types in the Principal Role. The type of property 'PriorityId' on entity 'tbl_pp_Message' does not match the type of property 'MessagePriorityId' on entity 'tbl_pp_MessagePriority' in the referential constraint 'tbl_pp_MessagePriority_tbl_pp_Message'.

If the navigation for tbl_pp_MessagePriority is removed from tbl_pp_Message POCO. And the navigation removed from tbl_pp_MessagePriority POCO back to tbl_pp_Message then it works.
With out the navigation removed it will generate a SQL statement like this.

```
insert [dbo].[tbl_pp_Message]
       ([Subject],
        [From],
        [Body],
        [PriorityId],
        [CreateDate],
        [CreateById],
        [tbl_pp_MessagePriority_MessagePriorityId])
values ('Test ENUM EF Code First 5.0' /* @0 */,
        'Daniel.Bivens' /* @1 */,
        'Test 01 Enum Body - The Magic Unicorn Edition' /* @2 */,
        2 /* @3 */,
        '2013-05-23T10:52:09' /* @4 */,
        5 /* @5 */,
        null)


select [MessageId]
from   [dbo].[tbl_pp_Message]
where  @@ROWCOUNT > 0
       and [MessageId] = scope_identity()
```

It would be ok if the tbl_pp_MessagePriority_MessagePriorityId was not added to the insert.

What can be done to keep the navigaion in EF code first while using ENUM support? Is there a DataAnnotation or a Mapping API?

Please post any suggestions you may have. This project is not using an EDMX/T4 template.

Working POCO:

```
public partial class tbl_pp_Message

    {
        //public tbl_pp_Message()
        //{
        //    this.tbl_pp_MessageDistribution = new List<tbl_pp_MessageDistribution>();
        //}

        public int MessageId { get; set; }
        public string Subject { get; set; }
        public string From { get; set; }
        public string Body { get; set; }
        public MessagePriorityEnum PriorityId { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }
        public int CreateById { get; set; }

        //[ForeignKey("PriorityId")]
        //public virtual tbl_pp_MessagePriority tbl_pp_MessagePriority { get; set; }
        //public virtual ICollection<tbl_pp_MessageDistribution> tbl_pp_MessageDistribution { get; set; }
    }




 public partial class tbl_pp_MessagePriority

    {
        //public tbl_pp_MessagePriority()
        //{
        //    this.tbl_pp_Message = new List<tbl_pp_Message>();
        //}

        public int MessagePriorityId { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> DisplayOrder { get; set; }
        public bool ShowAlert { get; set; }

        //public virtual ICollection<tbl_pp_Message> tbl_pp_Message { get; set; }
    }
```

The working POCO would be ok if no navigation was needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The thing I was missing was setting the look-up table primary key to the same ENUM type instead of an int.

Working POCO with ENUM and navigation.

```
public partial class tbl_pp_Message
  {
    public tbl_pp_Message()
    {
        this.tbl_pp_MessageAction = new List<tbl_pp_MessageAction>();
        this.tbl_pp_MessageAttachment = new List<tbl_pp_MessageAttachment>();
        this.tbl_pp_MessageDistribution = new List<tbl_pp_MessageDistribution>();
    }

    public int MessageId { get; set; }
    public string Subject { get; set; }
    public string From { get; set; }
    public string Body { get; set; }
    public MessageTypeEnum TypeId { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }
    public int CreateById { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("TypeId")]
    public virtual tbl_pp_MessageType tbl_pp_MessageType { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<tbl_pp_MessageAction> tbl_pp_MessageAction { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<tbl_pp_MessageAttachment> tbl_pp_MessageAttachment { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<tbl_pp_MessageDistribution> tbl_pp_MessageDistribution { get; set; }
}




 public partial class tbl_pp_MessageType
  {
    public tbl_pp_MessageType()
    {
        this.tbl_pp_Message = new List<tbl_pp_Message>();
    }

    [Key]
    public MessageTypeEnum MessageTypeId { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> DisplayOrder { get; set; }
    public bool ShowAlert { get; set; }

   public virtual ICollection<tbl_pp_Message> tbl_pp_Message { get; set; }
}
```